# I don't understand RaycastCommand

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

Documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand.html) says:

> If maxHits is larger than the actual number of results for the command
>   the result buffer will contain some invalid results which did not hit
>   anything. The first invalid result is identified by the collider being
>   null. The second and later invalid results are not written to by the
>   raycast command so their colliders are not guaranteed to be null. When
>   iterating over the results the loop should stop when the first invalid
>   result is found.

Soo, having

```
new RaycastCommand(from, direction, 4);
```

1. How can i distinguish if i had no hits vs when result is invalid? Both cases have hit.collider == null.
2. If collides with multiple elements, rather than returning the nearest colliding one, it will return nothing??

Comment: According to the documentation, invalid means that it wasn't a hit. That means, if `results[0].collider == null` after it is complete, then there were no hits. The documentation does not describe any ordering to the results, so you may need to check all of the valid results to find the nearest hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RaycastHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) is a `struct` type thus itself can never be `null`. So as the docs says

> The first invalid result is identified by the collider being `null`.

---

**NOTE**: The order of the (optional) parameters in the [constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand-ctor.html) if not explicitly named is

```c#
new RaycastCommand(Vector3 from, Vector3 direction, float distance, int layerMask, int maxHits);
```

and their default values are

- `distance` = `float.MaxValue`
- `layerMask` = `-5`
- **`maxHits` = `1`**

Again in words: **The default value for `maxHits` is `1`!**

*Unfortunately this is not visible in the docs but your IDE should reveal that.*

---

Knowing this now you can see that your current example

```c#
new RaycastCommand(from, direction, 4);
```

actually says: The maximum **distance** of the ray is `4` but still allows **only `1` single hit**!

If you rather wanted to have `4` possible hits you have to call it as

```c#
new RaycastCommand(from, direction, maxHits: 4);
```

now if you call it like this a buffer with exactly `4` `RaycastHit` entries will be created, no matter how many objects are hit or if any at all.

---

Then nothing was hit at all if

```c#
results[0].collider == null
```

and since unfortunately

> The second and later invalid results are not written to by the raycast command so their colliders are **not guaranteed to be `null`**.

you would have to filter them e.g. like

```c#
var validResults = new List<RaycastHit>();
foreach(var r in results)
{
    if(r.collider == null) break;

    validResults.Add(r);
}
```

Then you could further also sort them to "nearest first" using Linq like e.g.

```c#
using System.Linq;

...

var orderedResults = validResults.OrderBy(r=>r.distance).ToList();

// Which is basically a shorthand for something like the following
// not sure though how Linq does it internally, I hope it does something more efficient ^^
var orderedResults = new List<RaycastHit>();
foreach(var r in validResults)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < orderedResults.Count; i ++)
    {
        if(orderedResults[i].distance <= r.distance)
        {
            orderesResult.Insert(i + 1, r);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't 4 the distance, rather than the amount of rays?

Comment: @FrakyDale honestly I don't know ^^ .. it's not really clear in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand-ctor.html) which constructors exist and I'm writing only on the phone right now so I had to work with what OP provided. But now that you mentioned it it seems legit since at least `Physics.Raycast` would then have the same signature, thanks ;)